# How can i do shooting mechanic on unity2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

i want a shooting mechanic but i cant spawn bullet on front of my gun.

[Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qepy6.png)

This circle always looking my cursor with a Z rotation so i cant spawn bullets with x or y axis i need to base Z rotation but i dont know how can i do.
Anyone can help it? Thanks.

I tried to change instantiate's position to 'dir' but this time normally the bullets spawning on my cursor position. And i dont know why, after the bullets spawn they z position becomes -20.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class main : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject gun,bullet;


    private Vector3 mousePos, dir;
    float rotateZ;

    private void Update()
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, transform.position.z));
        dir = mousePos - gun.transform.position;
        rotateZ = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,rotateZ);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            shoot();
        }
        
    }
    void shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(bullet,gun.transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try change `Quaternion.Identity` into `gun.transform.rotation` and see if it worked?

Comment: As for the `dir` thing, not much info provided so I can only guess. But before answering that question, you need to understand that `dir` is a direction, not a `position`. these two ideas are both `vector` in Unity, so it's important not to mix them up. As for why the bullets are instantiated at mouse then, I guess your gun is at (0,0,0), therefore `mousePos - (0,0,0) = mousePos = dir`, thus making bullets instantiated on your mouse position.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang I tried change Quaternion.Identity to gun.transform.rotation but its cant be solution because its rotation value, i wanna change position value. This only serves to create clones in the same rotation as the gun.

Comment: Question's a bit unclear, but if you (also?) want the bullet to spawn in front of the gun ( = from gun's position towards cursor), then it's `Instantiate(bullet, gun.transform.position + dir * 1, ...)`. You can change the `1` to other numbers to indicate how far it should be spawned from gun.

Answer (score 0):

To spawn a bullet in front of your gun in Unity, you can use the following steps:

1. Create a new GameObject for your bullet.
2. Add a Rigidbody2D component to the bullet GameObject.
3. Create a new script for your bullet and attach it to the bullet GameObject.
4. In the bullet's script, add the following code:

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public float speed = 10f;

       void Start()
       {
           // Get the direction of the bullet.
           Vector2 direction = gun.transform.position - transform.position;

           // Normalize the direction.
           direction.Normalize();

           // Set the bullet's velocity.
           GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * speed;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Back in your main script, add the following code to the shoot()
   method:

   ```
   void shoot()
   {
       // Create a new bullet GameObject.
       GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, gun.transform.position, gun.transform.rotation);

       // Add force to the bullet in the direction of the gun barrel.
       newBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(gun.transform.forward * 100f);
   }
   ```

This code will create a new bullet GameObject at the position of the gun barrel and rotate it to match the rotation of the gun barrel. It will then add force to the bullet in the direction of the gun barrel.

To make sure that the bullet always spawns in front of the gun, you can use the following code:

```
Vector3 spawnPosition = gun.transform.position + gun.transform.forward;
GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, spawnPosition, gun.transform.rotation);
```

This code will create the new bullet GameObject at the position of the gun barrel plus the distance to the tip of the gun barrel. This will ensure that the bullet always spawns in front of the gun.

I hope this helps!

Comment: My project is 2d so transform.forward is not working.